# Implementing last_login

Tags: atk4

I was wondering which you think is the best way to implement a "last login", saving on a table the date and showing it to the user when he logins on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply adding a last_login field to your users model -and mysql table-, so you can easily get and update

Just like in the bottom of this page:
http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/auth

Comment: just wanted to add that `auth->check()` returns "true" only when user is first time authenticated. On following requests it adds false. If you are using models, then you can use `$user->set('last_login',date('Y-m-d'))->update();`

Comment: Good point, I've implemented on my index.php the next thing (first show "last login" and then doing a dsql()->do_update() to update the data                                                                    
         $this->add('View_HtmlElement')->setElement('H5')->set('Ultimo Acceso: '.$this->api->auth->get('lastlogin'));


        $this->api->db->dsql()->table('user u')
                 ->set('lastlogin',date('Y-m-d G:i:s'))
                 ->where('id',$this->api->auth->get('id'))
                 ->do_update();